# is there a common way to avoid crash on -[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (i) beyond bounds

Tags: ios, iphone

I hope to help other person to fix the bug of a project

I notice all most more than 1/2 of total bugs are

-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (i) beyond bounds

```
NSRangeException(SIGABRT)

-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (3) beyond bounds (3)
0   CoreFoundation  0x00000001822682d8  ___exceptionPreprocess
1   libobjc.A.dylib     0x0000000193a940e4  objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation  0x0000000182268218  -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3   CoreFoundation  0x0000000182165a9c  -[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]
4   SoYoungMobile40     0x00000001000bae98  0x0000000100030000 + 568976
5   SoYoungMobile40     0x00000001001609c0  0x0000000100030000 + 1247680
6   UIKit   0x0000000186d0c77c  -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:]
7   UIKit   0x0000000186d0a754  -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:]
8   UIKit   0x0000000186d06004  -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews]
9   UIKit   0x0000000186ca5760  -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
10  QuartzCore  0x00000001865ede1c  -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
11  QuartzCore  0x00000001865e8884  CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
12  QuartzCore  0x00000001865e8728  CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
13  QuartzCore  0x00000001865e7ebc  CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
14  QuartzCore  0x00000001865e7c3c  CA::Transaction::commit()
15  QuartzCore  0x000000018663e1f4  CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long)
16  IOKit   0x0000000183419470  IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 376
17  CoreFoundation  0x000000018220adc4  ___CFMachPortPerform
18  CoreFoundation  0x000000018221fa54  ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
19  CoreFoundation  0x000000018221f9b4  ___CFRunLoopDoSource1
20  CoreFoundation  0x000000018221d934  ___CFRunLoopRun
21  CoreFoundation  0x00000001821492d4  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
22  GraphicsServices    0x000000018b95f6fc  GSEventRunModal + 156
23  UIKit   0x0000000186d0efac  UIApplicationMain + 1476
24  SoYoungMobile40     0x0000000100445590  0x0000000100030000 + 4281744
25  libdyld.dylib   0x0000000194112a08  _start
```

from the information send back from user, I can not locate where the crash exactly.

Is there a common way to avoid index beyond bounds error.

My way is put some code before objectAtIndex, but I do not know if this is OK.

Your comment welcome

Comment: `if (index < [array count])`? Else, it could be your code that may need a check more than "patch the crash": i.e. a miscalculation, etc.

Comment: You avoid the crash by not using indexes `>= count`.  There is no reason to code defensively as it's a submission that you have lost control of your code base.

Comment: @Droppy The reality of software development is that you don't always have control over the parameters passed to your code, but you DO have control over how your code handles it. Thus, I would disagree with your assertion that *"there's no reason to code defensively."* Something like this sounds like a good candidate for an `NSAssert`.

Comment: @Mike Of course validating of data is a different thing altogether, however the suggestion here is that every array access is couched in a range check.  In which case I assert the programmer has lost control.

Comment: @Droppy, right. I don't disagree in principle, but I suppose I'm responding to the idea that "losing control" is something you can or should try to prevent. I write a good amount of open source software, and obviously have complete control over my code, but almost no control over how that code is used, what params are passed to it, etc. We might not be in disagreement, perhaps it's a semantics thing.

Comment: @arachide I would personally try to follow the stack trace and figure out the *actual cause* of this issue, rather than mask it by wrapping it in an if-statement. This is a bug and should be squelched.

Comment: @Mike That isn't what's happening here; the question isn't about validation of parameters passed by a third party.  The code that's crashing is a tableview datasource accessing an array out-of-bounds and the OP wants a solution to stop a crash.  He is trying to hide errors in his code.  That is not to be encouraged.

Comment: @Droppy, As I said, it doesn't look like we're in disagreement. In my opinion, the core problem here "isn't control over code", its a bug that needs to be fixed instead of masked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (index >= 0 && index < array.count) {
    id object = array[index];
} else {
    #ifdef DEBUG
        // catch any bugs in development
        [NSException raise:@"Index out of bounds." format:@"Index (%@) is out of bounds of array (%@)", index, array.count];
    #else
        NSLog(@"Index out of bounds.");  // log in release
    #endif
}
```

Comment: @arachide I would also add an else branch that asserts in debug builds and logs in release build to help catch problems during development, and find them during release. Because you want to be able to find the root cause of why the array is out of bounds, not just skip over it and ignore it.

Comment: Agreed; `else { [NSException raise:@"I've lost control"]; }`.

Comment: Thanks, but it is for development mode. if it is same OK for production environment also?. I hope the app prompt warning message rather than crashe and lost user.

Comment: Well the user shouldn't have a way to cause an index out of bounds exception. If one of these exceptions is generated, then it is a bug and the programmer messed up and it should be logged; the user should not ever be able cause an index out of bounds exception. This code will produce an exception in development so that the programmer knows exactly when and where it happened. In production, it will just log it and move on.

Comment: @Gruntcakes I am using the online bug tracker, but sometime the feedback information is not enough to locate the bug

Answer (score 3):

You ***can*** do something like what has been proposed by others, like wrap the index in an if-statement before using it, but ***I wouldn't recommend it in the case you're describing***.

While you're able to debug it, you should. Following the stack trace from the exception, find the code that is using an invalid array index, and fix it. This is a bug and the "way to prevent the crash" is to fix it, not mask it, IMHO.